# Hide/Show some HTML table cells individually and align the remaining cells as they belong to the same row

Tags: html, html-table, rows, expand

The best way I can explain my problem is showing an example. I have the HTML jQuery table showed on the link below, that has a header (blue) and four rows, whose cells are in green, white and grey color. I just want the white and grey cells to hide/show alternately (toogle) by clicking on green cells, which would remain always visible as parent cells. After hiding white cells, the green ones should be aligned into the same row, as they would fit like tetris bricks. That's all, I think more clear is impossible.

[image]

The table code:

```
<table class="columns" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
  <td class="left" rowspan="2">
      <div style="text-align:center;"></div>    </td>
    </tr><tr><td class="middle">
    <div id="detail_table_source" style="display:none"></div>
    <p>Expanded</p>
    <table id="detail_table" class="detail">
      <colgroup>
      <col style="width:20px;">
      <col style="width:40px;">
      <col style="width:70px;">
      <col style="width:20px;">
      </colgroup>
      <thead>
        <tr bgcolor="#848FA4">
          <th width="88" bgcolor="#729ADE">Blahhh</th>
          <th width="211" bgcolor="#729ADE">BLAHH</th>
          <th width="229" bgcolor="#729ADE">BLAHH</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="#50C43C" class="parent" id="row456" style="cursor: pointer; " title="Click to expand/collapse"><strong>Blahh</strong></td>
          <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="child-cell456">blah blah</td>
          <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="child-cell456">blah blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan="4" valign="top" bgcolor="#5B5B5B" class="child-row456">&nbsp;</td>
          <td bgcolor="#50C43C" class="parent" id="cell456" style="cursor: pointer; " title="Click to expand/collapse">blah blah </td>
          <td bgcolor="#50C43C" class="parent" id="cell456" style="cursor: pointer; " title="Click to expand/collapse">blah blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="child-cell456">blah blah</td>
          <td class="child-cell456" >blah blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="child-cell456">blah blah</td>
          <td class="child-cell456">blah blah</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

And the CSS style:

```
<style>
table.detail, table.detail td, table.detail th {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    text-align:left;
    padding:.5em 1em;
}
table.detail tr.parent {
    width:6em;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#99CC00;
    border-width:1px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    padding:2px 10px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please provide your html, it's unclear what your after.

Comment: yes it is possible. Do you have any code you've tried?

Comment: If you want to delete, press the [delete] button under your question's tags.

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what the question is, but yeah, you can use whatever classes you feel like on table cells.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="a"></td>
        <td class="b"></td>
        <td class="c"></td>
        <td class="d"></td>
        <td class="e"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="f"></td>
        <td class="g"></td>
        <td class="h"></td>
        <td class="i"></td>
        <td class="j"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="k"></td>
        <td class="l"></td>
        <td class="m"></td>
        <td class="n"></td>
        <td class="o"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe it's been rolled back.

Comment: thank you, Gromer. I deleted the question because I was thinking of remaking it later, since comments and votes said it was an unclear question, but then I let it go since it was too late. Referent to the question, I added already the "class" property inside <td> tags, using parent or child string, but all together doesn't work. I just want a table whose parent rows (always visible) or child rows (toggleable) are not the common straight rows stuck one over the other, but groups of cells from different rows that would act like they were from the same row.

Comment: Assuming that the question is correctly formuled and meet with the approval of all people, how many time do I have to wait to get votes enough to have my question reopened? A century?. Will it happen some time?. I can't even delete this post, to open a new one with the corrected question, cause probably I would get it closed because of duplicated questions. Sincerely, this site is the most useless and annoying helping site ever.